# I want to scroll page with a link_to (ruby on rails)

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

It is a exemple for illustre my topic
it a code for scroll at different part of the page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#section1 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#section2 {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Smooth Scroll</h1>

<div class="main" id="section1">
  <h2>Section 1</h2>
  <p>Click on the link to see the "smooth" scrolling effect.</p>
  <a href="#section2">Click Me to Smooth Scroll to Section 2 Below</a>
  <p>Note: Remove the scroll-behavior property to remove smooth scrolling.</p>
</div>

<div class="main" id="section2">
  <h2>Section 2</h2>
  <a href="#section1">Click Me to Smooth Scroll to Section 1 Above</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So my question it is possible to do this with a link_to with ruby on rails ?

I use ruby on rails an i want a anchor link to jump to a specific part of a page ^^

Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Looking into https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to i guess you'd just pass the hash and id as the second param into the `link_to` function like:

```
<%= link_to "Click Me to Smooth Scroll to Section 2 Below", "#section2" %>
```